# Compare AES with MD4 or another

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, hash, checksum

Could somebody compare the safety of algorithms `AES-CMAC` with only 5 rounds, `MD4` or some else hash function for checksums? Both in terms of speed and safety. We want fast and reliable checksum for detecting random error changes in streams (no bad guys involved). Ideally also with standard `C/C++` implementation.

Comment: If you want reliable checksum then use SHA-512, if you want it fast then use CRC32. Do you need to detect anyone messing with the stream or just communication channel errors ?

Comment: CRC32 is non-crypto and fairly slow, SHA-512 is crypto but slow.

Comment: You can simply try out the speed for yourself, on your target platform. If you just want error detection, you should provide some more information on the context; i.e. if you only have 2 different inputs, the checking-algorithm hardly matters ;)

Comment: Could you compare the safety of `AES-CMAC` with 10 rounds and with only 5 rounds???

Comment: CRC32 is (much) faster than the algorithms you named... and again: do you need to detect tampering with the data or communication channel error ?

Comment: @Yahia: You're wrong. http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html

Comment: @James from your link: AES-CMAC takes 16.1 cycles per byte while CRC32 takes only 6.9 - proving my point that CRC32 is faster.

Comment: @Yahia: AES-CMAC has originaly 10 rounds, `MD5` takes even 6.8 cycles and `MD4` even faster. But speed is not the only concern.

Comment: @James without an answer to "do you need to detect tampering with the data or just communication channel error ?" this discussion won't yield any result...

Comment: @Yahia: Sorry, just the communication channel errors. No bad guys involved.

Comment: @James: Then you don't want something with the complexity of AES; it's not designed with parity-checking in mind.

Comment: if no bad guys involved I would really opt for CRC32 - it is designed for this kind of stuff AND it is rather fast AND it can even be used to correct 1-bit-errors

Comment: @Yahia: I'm pretty sure a CRC can't be used to **correct** errors...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth you are right, I confused it with another algorithm...

Comment: look at some basic telecommunictaions theorie there you will find things like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_code, Reed SOlomon(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed_Solomon), CRC and the like. If you know alittle about the errors how many bits, burst errorlength, etc and error detection only (resend data) or error correction as well you can select something suiting your needs

Comment: CRC is excellent at detecting random errors. You may want a CRC64 if you are sending terabytes of data.

Comment: I would not recommend to use a variant of AES with a lower number of rounds ... Rijndael was designed with the number of rounds used in the standard, and is only really secure with this number (or higher ones).

Answer (score 1):

CRCs are explicitly designed to detect transmission errors; unlike hashes they provide concrete guarantees on what errors they will definitely detect. If it's transmission errors rather than an adversary you're concerned about, use a CRC.

Comment: So why majority of, e.g. ISO images, is protected against transmission/disk faults with crypto-hashes (`MD5, SHA1...`)?

Comment: @James Several reasons: 1) A cryptographic hash is longer than any typically used CRC, and so is more resistant to multiple transmission errors for large files, 2) They're convenient and easily available for people to verify, and 3) Transmission errors aren't the only thing distributors worry about - an adversary is also a possibility.